# ag-grid data is not filtered after setting quick filter

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have a component where I modify it's view based on values of some observable, such that the component is not destroyed, but just hiding some elements.
I have a grid inside this component that is not hidden no matter what the value is.
along with this grid, there's an `input` element that is being used to set a quick filter for ag-grid.
It's working fine regularly, but when I take this action of hiding some of the elements. the grid just stopped functioning as usual.

I've checked using `gridApi.getQuickFilter()` and the quickfilter that I send is being applied, it just doesn't affect the results that are displayed on the grid.
also tried to refresh cells and reset the filter, but it didn't change anything.

Any ideas as to why this is happening would be helpful.

if there's a need to share some code please ask.

Comment: Can you provide us an example on an online code editor?